# Have Excel Show Numbers instead of text

Tags: excel, date

I was given a problem set and dates show up for example as 1/1/2016 on the side and are converted automatically to Jan-16. How do I have it so it just says 1/1/2016?

Comment: Change the format to "Short Date". Or a custom Format of "mm/dd/yy" or "dd/mm/yyyy" depending on your local settings.

Comment: @ScottCraner thank you worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly format the cell as text instead of automatic. After this, it might be neccesary to re-enter the text.

Another option is to prefix the text with a tick character `'`.